# how to save url created from canvas.toBlob() inside PDFJS.getDocument to array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, pdf.js

I render the pdf page on canvas. Then, I want to save url created from canvas blob to array so that I can access outside of this method. I can save it to array. But when I console.log array it show me `{key:Array(0)}`instead of `{key:Array(2)}` . 0 should be 2 in my case because I added two values. I can see the values of array on console. But, could not access values  by index outside of this method.

> Outside the method:

[image: outside the method]

> Inside the method (I show second output from loop so it show all
>   values inside):

[image: inside the method]

In second output it shows `Array(2)` that are numbers of value inside.

I could not access the value with the index(`a['key'][0]`). It show undefined. When I try inside the function, It show desired output.

```
<?php
ob_start();
require_once('../../../library/tcpdf/tcpdf.php');
$pdf = new TCPDF();
$pdf->setPrintHeader(false);
$pdf->setPrintFooter(false);
$pdf->AddPage();
$html_p1 = 'Text messaging, or texting, is the act of composing and sending electronic messages, typically consisting of alphabetic and numeric characters, between two or more users of mobile devices, desktops/laptops, or other type of compatible computer. Text messages may be sent over a cellular network, or may also be sent via an Internet connection';
//echo $html;
$pdf->writeHTML($html_p1, true, 0, true, 0);
$pdf->AddPage();
$html_p2 = 'A telephone call is a connection over a telephone network between the called party and the calling party.';
$pdf->writeHTML($html_p2, true, 0, true, 0);
$base64PdfString = $pdf->Output('', 'E');
$base64PdfArray  = explode("\r\n", $base64PdfString);
$base64          = '';
for($i = 5; $i < count($base64PdfArray); $i++)
{
    $base64 .= $base64PdfArray[$i];
}

?>

<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../../library/jquery/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../plugin/pdf-flipbook-master/pdfjs/build/pdf.js"></script>

    <script>
        //function
        const b64toBlob = (b64Data, contentType='', sliceSize=512) =>
            {
                const byteCharacters = atob(b64Data);
                const byteArrays = [];

                for (let offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += sliceSize)
                {
                    const slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);
                    const byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);
                    for (let i = 0; i < slice.length; i++)
                    {
                        byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
                    }
                    const byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
                    byteArrays.push(byteArray);
                }

                const blob = new Blob(byteArrays, {type: contentType});
                return blob;
            }
            function getCanvasBlob(canvas) 
            {
              return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) 
              {
                canvas.toBlob(function(blob) 
                {
                  resolve(blob)
                })
              })
            }
    </script>
        <script>

            $(document).ready(() =>
                {
                    const contentType   ='application/pdf';
                    const b64Data       ='<?php echo $base64;?>';
                    const blob          =b64toBlob(b64Data, contentType);
                    const blobUrl       =URL.createObjectURL(blob);

                    var a={key:[]};
                        PDFJS.getDocument({ url: blobUrl }).then(function(pdf_doc)
                        {

                            __PDF_DOC       = pdf_doc;
                            __TOTAL_PAGES   = __PDF_DOC.numPages;

                            var div_container = document.querySelector('.flipbook');
                            for(let i=1; i<=__TOTAL_PAGES; i++) 
                            {
                                pdf_doc.getPage(i).then(function(page)
                                    {

                                        var scale = 1;
                                        var viewport = page.getViewport(scale);

                                        var pag1        =document.createElement('canvas');
                                        //pag1.id           ='Pg_1';
                                        //$("#Pg_1").hide();
                                        var context1    =pag1.getContext('2d');
                                        pag1.height     =viewport.height;
                                        pag1.width      =viewport.width;

                                        var renderContext =
                                        {
                                            canvasContext: context1,
                                            viewport: viewport
                                        };

                                        page.render(renderContext).then(function()
                                            {
                                                div_container.appendChild(pag1);
                                                pag1.toBlob(function(blob)
                                                {
                                                    var burl                        =URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                                                    a['key'].push(burl);
                                                    console.log(a);
                                                    console.log(a['key'][0]);
                                                }, 'image/png');


                                                /*c_blob=getCanvasBlob(blob);
                                                c_blob.then(function(blob) 
                                                {
                                                         //do stuff with blob
                                                        var burl                        =URL.createObjectURL(blob); 
                                                        a['key'].push(burl);    
                                                }, function(err) {
                                                    console.log(err)
                                                });*/
                                                //$("#Pg_1").remove();

                                            });
                                    });
                            }

                        })
            console.log(a['key'][0]);
            console.log(a);
            //b={key:[]}
            //b['key'].push(1234);
            //console.log(b);
                })
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="flipbook"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Variable `a` is inside the anonymous function that runs when the document is ready -- 
 it is not globally scoped. It will work if you move the line

```
var a={key:[]};
```

before the line

```
$(document).ready(() =>
```

which will make it a global variable.

Comment: Thank you for response. @Samyok Nepal, I tried. But , still showing same result.